# Turn modified table column into integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table with one column which denotes a date. The date is displayed as MM/YY. I need to find all dates which are in the year 2025.

I have done the following:

```
ecom["Date"].str[3:]
```

So that I only have the year.

```
ecom["Date"].str[3:] == 25
```

This return a bunch of Booleans which are all false even when they are in the year 2025.

This is because:

```
ecom["Date"].str[3:]
```

Is not a number. If I input

```
int(ecom["Date"].str[3:])
```

I am told that

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I would like to know how to implement int (or similar).
I am also well aware I can declare 25 as a string as this also works however I would like to know specifically how to turn ecom["Date"].str[3:] into a number.

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you try ecom["Date"].astype(int32) or ecom["Date"].astype(float)?

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` is safer I'd say: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by FHTMitchell `pd.to_numeric` is the better option.